# Cycles, material with color based on height and backside in different colors

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

I am trying to set up a Cycles texture to render figures for a math textbook.  I am new to blender and am having trouble.  I am looking for an effect similar to

[image: graph1]

or

[image: graph2]

Ideally the front and back surfaces would be rendered in different colors and a surface would be transparent enough to see another surface behind it, but its back faces would not show up in the transparent parts.

Comment: Please explain in more depth what you are asking. Is it the texture or the graph you want to replicate? And what do you mean with the back faces not showing up in the transparent parts?

Comment: What have you tried so far and what specific aspect of this are you having trouble with? Is it the modelling or the material?

Comment: I have no trouble generating the geometry.  I have trouble with the specularity, diffusion, and making the front and back surfaces different.

Comment: I think you can find your answer here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2082/how-can-i-make-a-material-only-apply-to-a-side-of-a-plane

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A basic way to control the color based on height would be to use the coordinates on the Z axis and have those control a color ramp.

[image]

To have the backside be a different color use bacfacing, from the geometry node, to control the mix with a different shader.

[image]

From there on, is just a matter of making the material as complex as you want until you are happy with the results.

[image]

or

[image]

Endless fun playing with textures.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This looks really neat.  Is there a way to use "whether a certain texture has passed through a transparent region" as an input parameter for some node?  For example, suppose the front surface is front1 and the back is back1.  If front1 could be seen through a transparent object, it would be unmodified, but if bak1 was seen through a transparent object, the color would be modified.

Comment: That can be done with the lightpath node. http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28422/how-to-render-a-mesh-transparent-with-a-color-on-its-edges-only-with-nodes/28423#28423 but please do ask new questions on different posts, to keep things organized