# How to remove lines from wireframe...?

Tags: mesh, materials, subdivision-surface, wireframe, nurbs-surface

I made a surface and added a wireframe modifier on top of that. I want to remove just horizontal lines from the mesh. How can I do that..? Please help. I have highlighted it in the picture below.
[image]

Comment: An option is to use Freestyle line rendering where you can mark the edges you want.

Comment: The wireframe modifier will show the vertices and edges that make the mesh. Don't use that, instead, use a texture that has the lines going in the direaction you need them. Read tjhis related post: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67142/cycles-material-with-color-based-on-height-and-backside-in-different-colors/67145#67145

Answer (score 1):

I think that the easiest solution would be to remove wireframe modifier from this mesh,duplicate and separate from it edges, that you want to be thicker and add the wireframe modifier to this new mesh.