# Color an object according to it's slope using blender

Tags: texturing, color

I would like to colour the surface of a wedge-shaped object according to the slope of its surface using blender. I tried the solution provided in [Color a surface according to its slope](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/124635/color-a-surface-according-to-its-slope) , but unfortunately it only applies the colour ramp on the top of the object and not below (see image).

Do you have any suggestions on how to apply the colour ramp over the whole object?

[image: Wedge-shaped object with colour ramp but only until the middle of the wedge (lower part remains fully red)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Z component of the normal ranges from -1 (down) to 1 (up). Your *Color-Ramp* is capturing only 0-1, and clamping outside that range.

If you want a symmetrical response about horizontal, you could use the *Absolute* of Z:

[image]

If you wanted the full range to fit the ramp, from -1 down to 1 up, you could use *Map Range* (flipped if you want Top > Bottom to correspond to Left > Right):

[image]

If you wanted to encode the *angle* of the normal to the vertical, from 0° up to 180° down, you could map the *Arccosine* of the Z component from 0 to pi radians.

[image]

Comment: awsome! Thank you for your elaborate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the Z-component of your normals is within the range [-1,1] while your `ColorRamp` only maps the [0,1] range. Thus the lower half of your mesh is just clamped to 0 and looks all red.

An easy fix would be to use the use two `Math` nodes before feeding the Z-component of your normal into your ramp. The first one adds `1.0` the second one devides by `2.0`.