# Can't flip ColorRamp vertical using Mapping node (Cycles)

Tags: materials, texture-coordinates

I've been following [this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5491/how-do-i-colour-a-3d-terrain-based-on-its-height) to ColorRamp my mountains according to height - however as much as i fiddle around with the X, Y and Z axis they seem to have no effect vertically and simply point towards each corner.

[image: what it looks like]

Here's my node set up.

[image: nodes]

Is there something I'm missing? Maybe a node? Thanks for the help! (Yes it is unwrapped and in cycles)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like if you plug your *Mapping* node into a *Converter* > *Separate XYZ* node then put the Z outlet into the *ColorRamp* node, it works fine. You could also change the values of the *Mapping* node to have a vertical gradient (-35°, 45°, 0°).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

tested it and it works on other objects, so i think the problem is with you mesh. How is it generated? Maybe the polys aren't really there yet (EditMode) to work with object z coords.