# How do I apply different colours to an object that change depending on the z location of the object to make a contoured heightmap?

Tags: python, color, height-map

I have a heightmap of the height of terrain above and below sea level as a single object. I wish to colour it such that any part of the object that is below sea level (z<0) is coloured blue, and any part above sea level (z>0) is coloured green. How would I do this using a python script?

Comment: Hello, how do you want to apply the color ? Vertex colors ? Texture map ? Procedural shader ?

Comment: @Gorgious whichever would take the least time to execute whilst putting the change in colour at exactly z=0

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5491/how-do-i-colour-a-3d-terrain-based-on-its-height

Comment: Yeah those are what I would like to do but using a python script.

Comment: ... yeah initially closed as dupe, then re-opened since the question related to  python. Dupe gives examples of a material to create. There are numerous answers re adding a material with python.  Sometimes you can make _no effort_ and get lucky, sometimes not.  Also consider accepting and or up-voting  answers to your questions that have helped or answered them.